# Let A be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $A^{2}= I$. Prove that if $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$, then $A = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been trying to solve this for hours now and still have no idea. I have tried:

a) substituting $\lambda = 1$ into $\lambda x - Ax = 0$.

b) substituting $\lambda = 1$ into $\det(\lambda I-A)x = 0$.

Both ways have proven ineffective. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite $A^2-I$ as $\left(A+I\right)\left(A-I\right)$, and meditate on the kernel of $A+I$.

Comment: To make @darijgrinberg's nice suggestion clearer: on the one hand $A^2-I = 0$ - on the other do you see that $A+I$ is invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $(A+I)(A-I)=0$. If $1$ is the only eigenvalue, then $A+I$ is invertible. Therefore,
$$
     0=(A+I)^{-1}(A+I)(A-I)=A-I \implies A=I.
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have $A(x-A(x))=A(x)-A^2(x))=A(x)-x=-(x-A(x))$ thus $x-A(x)$ is a eigenvector with eigenvalue is $-1$, since $1$ is the only eigenvalue, $x-A(x)=0$, thus $x= A(x)$.

Comment: If x = A(x), why is A = Identity?

Comment: What is the identity for you?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, if x is not invertible, A is not necessarily the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$x^2-1$ is an annihilating polynomial of $A$. Hence, either it is the minimal polynomial (in which case there are $2$ eigenvalues) or the minimal polynomial is one of its divisors.